# Prove or disprove: a continuous function R → R is open if and only if it is strictly monotone.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Prove or disprove: a continuous function $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is open if and only if it is strictly monotone.

Does $f(x)=x^2$ disprove it? it sounds a bit to easy for me

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is not open, since it maps the open set $(-1,1)$ to the not-open set $[0,1)$.

Comment: Hint: If a map is not strictly monotone it will have a local minimum/maximum somewhere. Use that to show it can't be an open map for a similar reason as to why $x^2$ fails to be open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and strictly monotone, then for every $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(a,b)=\{f(x):a<x<b\}=\{f(x):f(a)<f(x)<f(b)\}=(f(a),f(b))$, so $f$ will be open. (because it sends open sets to open sets).

On the other hand, if $f$ is continuous but not strictly monotone, there are points $a<b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Then, since $f$ achieves a minimum and a maximum value in the interval $[a,b]$, $f((a,b))=[\min f([a,b]),\max f([a,b])]$ and we would conclude that $f$ is not open.

I guess then that, under the assumption that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f$ is open if and only if $f$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: I forgot to say: your example $f(x)=x^2$ is neither an open function nor strictly monotone, so does not work as a counterexample.

Comment: concise and clear. definitely a good answer +1

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=x^2$ is not open and it is not strictly monotone on $\mathbb{R}$. So your example does not disprove the assertion

Comment: Adding an example as to why it isn't open (which the OP may have believed was true) may be helpful, though. (for instance, $f((-\infty, 1)) = [0,\infty)$).

Comment: You're right, did you find any counter example then? or maybe its true? I did manage to prove the other direction (if f is open and continuous its strictly monotone)